# How to call a class in express().use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am learning Node JS with typescript but I got stuck with one problem. In `app.ts` file I have intialized the `express` and tried to call the router class inside `app.use()` method but its giving an error. Below is my code for the same:

**app.ts**

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import db from './models/database';
import { AuthRouter } from './routes/auth.routes';

export class App {
    app = express();
    ADMIN_URL = '/api/admin';
    PORTAL_URL = '/api/portal';

    constructor() {
        db.sequelize.sync().then(() => console.log('Drop and re-sync db'));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json({
            type: 'application/json',
            limit: '50mb'
        }));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            limit: '50mb',
            extended: true,
            parameterLimit: 50000
        }));
        this.enableCORS();
        this.adminApis();
    }
    private adminApis() {
        this.app.use(`${this.ADMIN_URL}/auth`, AuthRouter);  // This "AuthRouter" is giving error
    }

    private enableCORS() {
        this.app.use((req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) => {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
            'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
            'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

**auth.route.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { SignUp, Login, getAllAdmin, fetchUserDetails, updateAdminUser, deleteAdminUser, deleteAllAdminUser } from '../controller/auth.controller';
import verifySignUp from '../middlewares/verifySignUp';
import verifyToken from '../middlewares/authcheck';

export class AuthRouter {
    
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.setPOSTRoutes();
    }

    private setPOSTRoutes() {
        this.router.post('/createAdminUser', verifySignUp, SignUp);
        this.router.post('/login', Login);
    }
}
```

Below is the message the editor is showing when I hover on the commented line in **app.ts** file:

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type 'typeof AuthRouter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application'.
> Type 'typeof AuthRouter' is missing the following properties from type 'Application': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and
> 61 more.ts(2769)

How can I fix this? And also is there any sample project available on web for Node JS with Typescript using classes?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use),

> `app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])` : Mounts the specified
> middleware function or functions at the specified path: the middleware
> function is executed when the base of the requested path matches path.

[image]

You are passing your class as it is in the argument. You need to pass a valid callback as per the above image. See the linked docs for more examples.